# Android - Activate the appbar scrolling on a per viewpager recyclerview basis

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a ViewPager with 2 tabs containing a Recyclerview.
I am using support libraries 22.2.0 (AppCompat, Recycler view...).
My viewpager xml is initially :

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
   android:id="@+id/viewPager"
   app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

I would like to activate/desactivate the appbar scrolling on a per tab/recyclerview basis instead of on whole viewpager basis, that is, 
one tab/recyclerview will make the appbar scrolling and the other tab/recyclerview won't.

This issue is that when i remove

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

from  viewpager   a default layout_behavior is applied to viewpager which still activates appbar scroll on both tab/recyclerview.

My strategy is to desactivate the appbar scrolling in viewpager, maybe something like this :

```
   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_desactivated_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And activate it on my first tab/recyclerview  only. Like this :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    ...
    android:id="@+id/playlist1_rv"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

But I need a class for "@string/appbar_desactivated_behavior". 
Does it exist? Is not, how to write it? Or do you think about another strategy?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `ViewPager`, the appbar_scrolling_view_behavior needs to be set on the `ViewPager` for proper layout.

All you have to do is turn off nested scrolling in the `RecyclerView` that you don't want to scroll the app bar:

```
        recyclerview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Note that you may have issues with positioning and you may have to put an appbar-sized margin at the bottom of the recyclerview.  And if your user scrolls the appbar up with the other recyclerview then swipes to this recyclerview, there will be a space at the bottom of the page.